# Better approach to write query with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two sql queries to query email domain count as follow. which is a better approach to follow?

It also seems that both queries return the exact same execution plan but I do not understand why is it so.

First

```
SELECT emaildomain, 
       Count(email) AS Total 
FROM   (SELECT email, 
               Substring(email, Charindex('@', email) + 1, 
               Len(email) - Charindex('@', 
                            email)) 
               AS EmailDomain 
        FROM   [dbo].[tbluser]) A 
GROUP  BY emaildomain
```

Second

```
Select substring(email, charindex('@', Email) + 1,
Len(Email) - charindex('@', Email)) as EmailDomain,
count (Email) as Total
from [dbo].[tblUser]
GROUP BY substring(email, charindex('@', Email) + 1,
Len(Email) - charindex('@', Email))
```

Comment: They look identical to me. "Better" is opinion based.

Comment: Well, since both queries have the same execution plan, "Better" in this case can only be applied from a readability / maintainability point of view. 
In this case, it's opinion based - but IMHO the first option is more readable (mainly because it doesn't repeat the string manipulation code) and therefor is better. Having said that - I'm voting to close this question as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The execution plans should be the same.  Which is better depends on multiple factors, but either should be fine.

I want to suggest another alternative:

```
SELECT v.emaildomain, count(*) as total
FROM dbo.tbluser u CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (substring(u.email, Charindex('@', u.email) + 1, 
                        Len(u.email) - Charindex('@', u.email)
                       ) 
             )
     ) v(EmailDomain) 
GROUP BY vemaildomain ;
```

`APPLY` implements something called a "lateral join".  This has many uses.  But one use is to define new column aliases that do not require subqueries/CTEs.

Note that you can also simplify this logic as:

```
     (VALUES ( stuff(u.email, 1, charindex('@', u.email) + 1, '') )
     ) v(EmailDomain)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Execution Plan is the same for both, for me, the first query is cleaner than the second, personally, I prefer to use Common Table Expression (CTE), but it is equivalent to use a derived table.

The next time you can share the Execution Plan with this tool:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/